# How to delete DownloadManager cache folder?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm looking to delete file(s) at `/data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache` programmatically but do not seem to have access to it. I have signature level app permission and can do `adb root` and `su` in the shell but `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(su)` receives a `Permission denied` exception. When I try to do `File file = new File(path)` and check if it exists, it returns false. The permissions for the cache folder are `drwxrwx--x`.
 **How can I delete file(s) from the DownloadManager cache directory?**

**Update**

The best way seems to be to use `DownloadManager remove(downloadId)` which removes it from the cache folder. It is not well documented that it does that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way seems to be DownloadManager `remove(downloadId)` when you have it available. It actually removes the file with a message `Deleting /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/binary.apk via provider delete`

If you want the list of downloadIds to remove the whole cache, the programmer might need to use DownloadManager Query and filter by status complete to get all of them to remove.